# Using sockets to display video

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to achieve the following:

Let's say there are 3 devices: Device A | B | C.

Device B is server. Device A sends a video stream to device B. Now I want that when device C opens the webpage of device B, it sees the video stream sent by Device A.

I tried the following Java code:

```
socket = new Socket("192.168.0.103",1234);
ParcelFileDescriptor socketWrapper = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
// ...
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(socketWrapper.getFileDescriptor());
```

Now at server end, I'm confused how to get this response and display this video sent on a particular page, say 192.168.0.103/page

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `tried the following Java code:`. Where? On A, B or C?

Comment: @greenapps on A. This is client side code. 'C' would only view a URL in browser and should see the stream sent by A to B.